# Bootstrap lightbox controls (next/prev/close) not showing properly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, frontend, lightbox

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap image gallery with popup but as you notice below it's doesn't work properly. How can I fix this?

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Slideshow or Image Gallery -->

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=252" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=252" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=253" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=253" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

</div>

<div class="row">

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=254" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=254" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=255" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=255" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=256" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=256" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

</div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

$(this).ekkoLightbox();

});

</script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

[image]

In the other websites it works perfectly but when I copy-paste it, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I add the ekko-lightbox.css to your code the next/prev controls are in the right place for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.css">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!-- Slideshow or Image Gallery -->

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=252" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=252" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=253" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=253" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

</div>

<div class="row">

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=254" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=254" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=255" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=255" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

<a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=256" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery" class="col-md-4">

<img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=256" class="img-fluid rounded">

</a>

</div>

</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ekko-lightbox/5.3.0/ekko-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

$(this).ekkoLightbox();

});

</script>
  </body>
  </html>

enter image description here
```